# how to convert code that iterates with .iterrows() to .itertuples()

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using a lot of .iterrows() while looping through Pandas data frames, but my code is getting more slow especially when i'm iterating through large data sets with a lot of 'if' and other logic.

Usually my code is like this:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if df.loc[index, "column_name"] == something and df.loc[index, "column_name"] > 0:
         df.loc[index, "column_name"] = something
```

How can i replace .iterrows() with .itertuples() to make my code faster?

How can i achieve the same result with .itertuples()?

More info:

My data frame:

[image]

My code:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if df.loc[index, "product_name"] == 'sugar' and df.loc[index, "sold"] > 0:
         df.loc[index, "order"] = 5
```

I want to achieve the same result using .itertuples().

Comment: Your condition can't evaluate to `True`. If `column_name` contains the string `something` the second condition will cause a `TypeError`. If your conditions could be fulfilled without an error you wouln't need to iterate over the dataframe with a for loop.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

first thing, you don't need to use loc when asking on a single row in iteration

```
if row["product_name"] == 'sugar' and row["sold"] > 0:
         row["order"] = 5
```

second
try to avoid iteration

```
import numpy as np

my_condition = (df['product_name']=='sugar')&(df['sold']>0)

df['order'] = np.where(my_condition,5,0)
```